# Predefine WordPress publication time and time

Tags: wordpress

I'm just looking for a solution that will enter predefined date and time to every new post's editing window.

Due to some peculiarities of my site the post time should always be the same, only the dates may vary. But sometimes I have to add lots of posts bearing the same year and month and differ only by the date.

So the best solution would be to set desired fixed date and time for every new post, so that I could only edit the date if needed.

This would save my time greatly.

No matter if it would be a plugin or a functions.php code. But functions.php is preferred if it is able to interact with the backend.

Comment: I would recommend a JavaScript/jQuery solution. Target the input fields and set the values as desired on page load. Include this JavaScript through functions.php for new posts (you'll need some test in an if statement for that).

Comment: @Pim Schaaf, include **what** JavaScript? :)

Comment: :) well, you're going to have to write some yourself. I can't write/test it for you until coming wednesday. You can edit your question if you run into trouble. Let us know!

Comment: Would I ask this question if I'm able to solve this riddle myself? :)

Comment: well, I figured you could progress on a few hints. I'll see what I can do for you next week.

Comment: Actually a hint is mostly a thing I'm asking for (while a ready solution will be absolute best anyway! :)) Thanks in advance

Comment: so you're going to have to find a way to target the date/time input fields through JavaScript, so that you can change the values on page load. Those values then can be posted on save. Anyway, I'll get back to you if no one else does. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Automatic Post Date Filler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/automatic-post-date-filler)? It includes a JavaScript based solution as I suggested in comments earlier, packed in a plugin with some options. Does this satisfy your needs?

Comment: I've checked that plugin out before asking my question here. It is quite useful one, but it writes its settings to the database. I want to avoid unnecessary database entries, that's why I'm looking for function.php solution. I have also tried to edit its javascript part after you've told me about possible javascript solution, but with no success - I'm a total zero in JS, while I understand that the only thing I need is to replace its variables with constants.

Comment: For posts that require predefined date/time I mostly use the well known "duplicate post" snippet for functions.php, but adding, say `'post_date'   => '1983-12-01 03:00:00',` to its array of the new post attributes leads to nothing unfortunately, it just ignores the post time stated this way